# PortfolioAnalytics "dollar_neutral" constraint

Tags: r

I am working with PortfolioAnalytics, and am trying to compare portfolios that are net-long, net-short, and market-neutral using the small cap dataset in MPO package (the dataset is irrelevant to my question, as the same problem exists with all data sets I have tried).  Unfortunately, adding "active" or "dollar_neutral" constraint results in all assets being weight 0, rather than just the sum of weights being 0.  I ran this against several other baskets of stock data that I downloaded, and get the same peculiar behavior.  See code below:

```
rm(list=ls())
cat("\014") 
library(mpo)
library(PortfolioAnalytics)
library(ROI)
library(ROI.plugin.quadprog)
library(ROI.plugin.glpk)
data(smallcap.ts)
smlcp <- smallcap.ts[,1:20]

stocks <- colnames(smlcp)

#initialize portfolio
pspec.base <- portfolio.spec(stocks)

#min variance objective fn
pspec.uc <- add.objective(portfolio=pspec.base,type="risk",name="var")

#dollar_neutral constraint, min var portfolio
pspec.neutral <- add.constraint(portfolio=pspec.uc,type="active")

opt.neutral <- optimize.portfolio(smlcp,pspec.neutral,optimize_method="ROI")
```

Running the code results in:
    opt.neutral

```
***********************************
PortfolioAnalytics Optimization
***********************************

Call:
optimize.portfolio(R = smlcp, portfolio = pspec.neutral, optimize_method = "ROI")

Optimal Weights:
MODI  MGF  MEE FCEL  OII  SEB  RML AEOS  BRC  CTC  TNL  IBC  KWD TOPP RARE  HAR  BKE   GG GYMB KRON 
   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 

Objective Measure:
StdDev 
     0
```

However, changing the "active" constraint to "long_only" results in:

```
Optimal Weights:
  MODI    MGF    MEE   FCEL    OII    SEB    RML   AEOS    BRC    CTC    TNL    IBC    KWD   TOPP   RARE 
0.0000 0.8901 0.0000 0.0001 0.0007 0.0000 0.0437 0.0144 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0035 0.0290 0.0000 
   HAR    BKE     GG   GYMB   KRON 
0.0000 0.0010 0.0083 0.0000 0.0093
```

as we would expect.

Any idea why neither "active" nor "dollar_neutral"  work the way I am using them?

Also, to get a net short (net long), I assume we need to use "weight_sum" constraint with max_sum=-0.0001(min_sum=0.0001) and min_sum=-1(max_sum=1).  Doing this, however, results in 0 weights for all assets.  What am I missing here?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find the MPO package but, since you suggest this result is not particular to that set of assets, I reproduced your results using an alternate set of stocks.   It seems that the result from `optimize.portfolio`, all weights =  0., is correct.  When there are no constraints which prevent all weights from going to zero, as is the case in your problem, the minimum variance is 0.  To obtain a nonzero result for weights, you will have to include additional constraints or objectives.  For example, you could add a constraint that the portfolio return equal a target value.  Another possibility is to include maximizing return as a second objective.  An example of this is shown below:

```
  library(quantmod)
  library(PortfolioAnalytics)
# specify asset tickers  
  stocks <- c("MSFT","AAPL", "AMZN", "YHOO", "XOM", "CVX", "UNH", "NKE")
  prices <- do.call(cbind, 
                    lapply(stocks, function(x) getSymbols(x, from="2010-01-01", auto.assign=FALSE, warnings=FALSE)[,6]))
  colnames(prices) <- stocks
  returns <- diff(prices, arithmetic=FALSE, na.pad=FALSE) - 1
  rm(portf1, portf1_opt)
# create portfolio object
  portf1 <- portfolio.spec(assets=stocks)
#    set portfolio objectives as minimizing variance and maximizing return
  portf1 <- add.objective(portfolio=portf1, type="risk", name="var")
  portf1 <- add.objective(portfolio=portf1, type="return", name="mean")
#    set dollar-neutral or active constraint
  portf1 <- add.constraint(portfolio=portf1, type="active")
  portf1_opt <- optimize.portfolio(R=returns, portfolio=portf1, optimize_method="ROI", trace=TRUE)
  print(portf1_opt)
```

which gives the result:

```
Optimal Weights:
   MSFT    AAPL    AMZN    YHOO     XOM     CVX     UNH     NKE 
-0.7822  1.1316  0.3834  0.1024 -2.9652 -0.3480  1.6232  0.8548 
Objective Measure:
    mean 
0.003131 
   StdDev 
0.03957
```

Also, just to note,  `rm(list=ls())` shouldn't be included in a sample post since this may delete objects which the user wishes to preserve in their environment.